# Gitignore complete procedure to ignore folders

Tags: git

I juste added .gitignore text files with *.png inside as I read on some tutorials.
Then, I do a "git add *" and I have to ctrl-c it because it takes forever(note that I pushed individually the .gitignore files before with:

```
git add <path_to_my_PNG_files>/.gitignore
git commit -m"..."
git push
```

. Please note that, I have two folders at  (real path not shown due to confidentiality reasons) with 30k PNG images inside. I placed the aforementioned .gitignore files inside.

I also did:

```
git config --global core.excludesFile ~/.gitignore
```

Also, the gitignore files are uploaded in the remote folders (the ones with the 30k PNG).

None of that helps. still git add * takes forever (adding the files it should not add i guess).

Can someone post a complete, very detailed, procedure of how the .gitignore thing works (in which folders to put them, what commands to use, how do they work, how does git use them exaclty (e.g., when does it read/interpret/apply them), what is the chronology, e.g., when do you have to create/push them, etc. etc.), and when is git "aware" of them?! /how can we force git to be aware of them?. All the tutorials I found are almost useless/no details (e.g., "create a .gitigore file and its done.").

Comment: I think your problem is about caching, try this : git rm -r --cached . And then "git add ." Then commit new changes

Comment: thanks. I tried, still takes forever...

Comment: what is the normal procedure to ignore all *.png in any folder? And how make git aware of it?